# CRM v9 - Delete records based on ID from CRM Entity using C# Code

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365, unified-service-desk

I am using CRM version 9.0 and I want to delete all records with same ID in CRM through C#.

I want to achieve something like this (I am giving a SQL Query example just for reference purpose)

```
Delete from entityName where id = @id
```

Currently, I am creating records in CRM through my C# code using below

```
dictionary.Add("code", new CrmDataTypeWrapper(code, CrmFieldType.Raw));
dictionary.Add("id", new CrmDataTypeWrapper(id, CrmFieldType.Raw));
Guid EvntId = _client.CrmInterface.CreateNewRecord("entityname", dictionary, "", false, new System.Guid());
```

Now I want to write a code block before this logic which will delete all the records if they exist of the passed ID.

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete an Entity in CRM - you must first fetch the entity to get the `GUID` of the entity.

`IOrganizationService` interface contains a `Delete` method which required the entity type (`LogicalName`) and the GUID of the entity that CRM creates.

Here's how we do it.

```
QueryExpression oppQuery = new QueryExpression("opportunity");
oppQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "opportunityid" });
oppQuery.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("parentcontactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, contact.Id));

EntityCollection opportunities = crmSvc.RetrieveMultiple(oppQuery);

foreach (var opportunity in opportunities.Entities)
{
    service.Delete("opportunity", opportunity.Id);
}
```

---

This means that you can delete entities based on your condition by fetching the entities you need first based on your condition.

`oppQuery.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("<your id field>", ConditionOperator.Equal, <your id>));`

On this line you specify the condition used to delete the relevant entities.

Comment: Dear Adrian, Thank you for the reply but I want to delete records based on the ID only not the complete entitiy

Comment: @FaranSaleem This line `oppQuery.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("parentcontactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, contact.Id));` is the query you need to modify to delete entities based on your ID :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure whether or not those ids exist in Dynamics, you should try-catch your Delete attempt, because if you try to delete a record that does not exist in Dynamics, Dynamics will throw you a `FaultException`.

```
var ids = new Collection<Guid>();
foreach (var id in ids)
{
    try
    {
        _service.Delete("[entityName]", id);
    }
    catch (FaultException)
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compliment Adriani6 answer:

I think you are trying to delete a set of records which are having particular field value. But that field is named as `id` which is not a primary key.

There is no equivalent of the below SQL query in Dynamics CRM.

```
Delete from entityName where id = @id
```

You have to fetch all the entity records matching this condition of non-primary key using `service.RetrieveMultiple` and then iterate through the result set for each record to issue `service.Delete` request with primary key.

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("entityName");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "eventId", "code"});
query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("id", ConditionOperator.Equal, id));

EntityCollection events = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

foreach (var event in events.Entities)
{
    service.Delete("entityName", event.Id);
}
```